# Не работает команда из-за lambda True Telebot

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

Есть бот, три функции, третья не реагирует на команду /add из-за lambda true во второй функции.

```
 @bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
    def vacancy(message):
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1, resize_keyboard=True)
        markup.add('1', '2')
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Выберите число:", reply_markup=markup)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, query)
    
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda m: True)
    def query(message):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)
    
    @bot.message_handler(commands=['add'])
    def pull(message):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"added")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Перенеси** команду `add` из конца кода, **в центр**

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def vacancy(message):
    markup = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1, resize_keyboard=True)
    markup.add('1', '2')
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Выберите число:", reply_markup=markup)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, query)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['add'])
def pull(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"added")
       
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda m: True)
def query(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)
```